# Collecting a Vec with a custom struct

Tags: rust, vector, struct, types

I have recently started learning Rust and I currently am trying to create a collection of data from a fake API in order to manipulate the data after fetching and deserializing it:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
struct Post {
    user_id: i32,
    id: i32,
    title: String,
    body: String,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    // Begin: important part
    let posts = reqwest::get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .await?
        .json::<Vec<Post>>()
        .await?;

    let posts = posts
        .iter()
        .map(|post| post) // Imagine manipulating the post here, somehow
        .collect::<Vec<&Post>>();
    // End: important part

    println!("{:#?}", posts);

    Ok(())
}
```

This works fine. However, what I don't understand is, why the above works, while it does not work when try to do the whole operation in one go, like this:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    // Begin: important part
    let posts = reqwest::get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .await?
        .json::<Vec<Post>>()
        .await?
        .iter()
        .map(|post| post) // Imagine manipulating the post here, somehow
        .collect::<Vec<&Post>>();
    // End: important part

    println!("{:#?}", posts);

    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=cc8feb9835972f82a6cb681cbd2fffc6)

without the error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:15:17
   |
15 |       let posts = reqwest::get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
   |  _________________^
16 | |         .await?
17 | |         .json::<Vec<Post>>()
18 | |         .await?
   | |_______________^ creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
...
21 |           .collect::<Vec<&Post>>();
   |                                   - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
...
24 |       println!("{:#?}", posts);
   |                         ----- borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

I was expecting these two ways of approaching the problem to yield the same result and I don't understand why one works while the other yields an error and quite frankly I don't understand the error message either.

What exactly am I doing wrong, here? I suspect that it might have something to to with traits, but I don't see why it wouldn't fail (or succeed, respectively) in both cases then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question you should ask yourself is: in the second example, you want to collect to vectors of borrowed `Post`s; who owns the `Post`s? In the first example, the vector is owned by the variable `posts`, and therefore you can iterate over references of elements within the vector; but in the second case, the vector is built by the `.json()` method, moved "to you", but you don't store it somewhere, you immediately consume it to retrieve references to what it contains; once the statement ends, the intermediate vector that was built will be dropped (ie. freed) and the references will be invalid.

Maybe you didn't get a nice error message due to manipulation in the `.map(...)` call, however the error message I get with [your example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=07eac67d3b1f00606e656acb59601122) is

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:18:17
   |
18 |       let posts = reqwest::get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
   |  _________________^
19 | |         .await?
20 | |         .json::<Vec<Post>>()
21 | |         .await?
   | |_______________^ creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
...
24 |           .collect::<Vec<&Post>>();
   |                                   - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
...
28 |       println!("{:#?}", posts);
   |                         ----- borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

You see that Rust suggests you to do exactly what you did.

Comment: For this particular case, you shouldn't follow the compiler hint, though, but rather replace `iter()` with `into_iter()` and collect into a `Vec<Post>`. Otherwise, it will be impossible to do any modifications on the posts. All you could do would be collecting references to the exact posts in the first vector into a second vector, which seems rather pointless.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks, that helped me almost as much as the correct answer, because it made something click in my mind that should have clicked already.

Comment: I thoroughly misunderstood the otherwise helpful compiler error, but your answer opened my eyes, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: value of type `Vec<&Post>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&Vec<Post>>
```

indicates the differences in return types of both the approaches.

In second approach, you are trying to collect a `Vec<&Post>` directly from the `Iterator<Item=&Post>` returned by `.iter()` on a deserialized `Vec<Post>`. This does not work, because `.iter()` method returns an iterator over references to Post objects, not references to references to Post objects (which is what `Vec<&Post> expects`).